# do not keep the checkbox when close window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcheckbox

When I click open in Example, open the windowncheck window, in the window windowncheck I check to checkbox_5 and checkbox_6 then I press close, when I reopen windowncheck, checkbox_5 and checkbox_6 are no longer available. how to checkbox_5 and checkbox_6 not lost.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        qbtn = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(50,50)
        qbtn.move(50, 50)
        qbtn.setStyleSheet("color:red")
        qbtn.setStyleSheet("background-color:green")

        newwindow_button = QPushButton('open', self)
        newwindow_button.clicked.connect(self.windown)
        newwindow_button.resize(50,50)
        newwindow_button.move(150, 50)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Check state')
        self.show()

    def windown(self):
        self.ff = Windowcheck()
          
class Windowcheck(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Windowcheck, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listCheckBox = ["Checkbox_1", "Checkbox_2", "Checkbox_3", "Checkbox_4", "Checkbox_5",
                             "Checkbox_6", "Checkbox_7", "Checkbox_8", "Checkbox_9", "Checkbox_10" ]
        self.listLabel    = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ] 
        grid = QGridLayout()
        for i, v in enumerate(self.listCheckBox):
            self.listCheckBox[i] = QCheckBox(v)
            self.listLabel[i] = QLabel()
            grid.addWidget(self.listCheckBox[i], i, 0)
            grid.addWidget(self.listLabel[i],    i, 1)

        self.button = QPushButton("CheckBox")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.checkboxChanged)
        self.button_close = QPushButton("close")
        self.button_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.labelResult = QLabel()

        grid.addWidget(self.button,      10, 0, 1,2)  
        grid.addWidget(self.button_close,11, 0, 1,2)    
        grid.addWidget(self.labelResult, 12, 0, 1,2)  
        self.setLayout(grid)    
        self.show()

    def checkboxChanged(self):
        self.labelResult.setText("")
        for i, v in enumerate(self.listCheckBox):
            self.listLabel[i].setText("True" if v.checkState() else "False")
            self.labelResult.setText("{}, {}".format(self.labelResult.text(),
                                                     self.listLabel[i].text()))  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The programs load the information of their status in the RAM while it is running, after closing the application it is lost so that is why the information is not persistent. If you want the application to save a state prior to closing then you must store that information on the hard drive through a file. For example in Qt you can use QSettings to do that job:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.settings = QSettings()

        self.ff = Windowcheck()

        qbtn = QPushButton("Quit", self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.setGeometry(50, 50, 50, 50)
        qbtn.setStyleSheet("color:red; background-color:green")

        newwindow_button = QPushButton("open", self)
        newwindow_button.clicked.connect(self.ff.show)
        newwindow_button.setGeometry(150, 50, 50, 50)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle("Check state")

        self.readSettings()

    def readSettings(self):
        for i in self.settings.value("indexes", [], type=list):
            self.ff.listCheckBox[int(i)].setChecked(True)

    def saveSettings(self):
        indexes = self.ff.indexes
        self.settings.setValue("indexes", indexes)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super().closeEvent(event)
        self.saveSettings()


class Windowcheck(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Windowcheck, self).__init__(parent)
        texts = [
            "Checkbox_1",
            "Checkbox_2",
            "Checkbox_3",
            "Checkbox_4",
            "Checkbox_5",
            "Checkbox_6",
            "Checkbox_7",
            "Checkbox_8",
            "Checkbox_9",
            "Checkbox_10",
        ]
        self.listCheckBox = []
        self.listLabel = []

        grid = QGridLayout(self)

        for i, text in enumerate(texts):
            checkbox = QCheckBox(text)
            label = QLabel()
            grid.addWidget(checkbox, i, 0)
            grid.addWidget(label, i, 1)
            self.listCheckBox.append(checkbox)
            self.listLabel.append(label)

        self.button = QPushButton("CheckBox")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.checkboxChanged)
        self.button_close = QPushButton("close")
        self.button_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.labelResult = QLabel()

        grid.addWidget(self.button, 10, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.button_close, 11, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelResult, 12, 0, 1, 2)

    @property
    def indexes(self):
        return [
            i for i, checkbox in enumerate(self.listCheckBox) if checkbox.isChecked()
        ]

    def checkboxChanged(self):
        self.labelResult.clear()
        texts = []
        for label, checkbox in zip(self.listLabel, self.listCheckBox):
            text = "True" if checkbox.isChecked() else "False"
            label.setText(text)
            texts.append(text)
        self.labelResult.setText(", ".join(texts))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @nghiep  If answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour